# make integral symbol big using tasks package to make a list

Tags: tasks

I am trying to make am horizontal list using tasks the probem is integral symbol is too small. How can I make it big without affecting the horizontal list

```
  \begin{tasks}[counter-format =(tsk[1]), label-offset=1.25em](3)
         \task $\int(x-2)(x+2)dx$
         \task $\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}dx$
         \task $\int\sqrt[3]{x^{2}}dx$
 \end{tasks}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please don't post just a code snippet. Instead, please a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix.

Comment: Probably looking for `\displaystyle` or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `etoolbox` to set maths in displaystyle within the tasks environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tasks}{\everymath{\displaystyle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[counter-format =(tsk[1]), label-offset=1.25em](3)
  \task $\int(x-2)(x+2)\,dx$ ;%
  \task $\int\frac{1}{x√{x}}\,dx$ ;
  \task $\int√[3]{x^{2}}\,dx$.
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]